# Xpad tray icon not showing up on 22.04

Tags: 22.04, system-tray

On a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04LTS, I just installed Xpad via apt. Its tray icon should appear on the upper right but does not. In the settings of Xpad the box "Enable tray icon" is checked.

I tried indicator-sticky notes, and its tray icon does appear. What is wrong with Xpad? Can it be fixed?